# Where to access all `GameObjects` from?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity, just fiddling around. I see how to edit `GameObjects` within the Unity UI, but how do I access these objects programmatically?

For instance, I have a `Hero` object that I'd like to make a `Sphere` object as its `collider`. If I write a script and attach it to the `Hero` object, how do I access `Sphere` to make `Hero` its parent?

Comment: I would highly recommend go and watching the [Unity Tutorial Videos](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials), it teaches the basic concepts like the ones you are talking about. Start with the Roll-A-Ball tutortial and go from there.

Answer (score 3):

You can find GameObject with  [`GameObject.Find`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html).

> I have a Hero object that I'd like to make a Sphere object as its
>   collider. If I write a script and attach it to the Hero object, how do
>   I access Sphere to make Hero its parent?

```
//Find Hero
GameObject hero = GameObject.Find("Hero");

//Find Sphere 
GameObject sphere = GameObject.Find("Sphere");

//Make Hero parent of sphere
sphere.transform.SetParent(hero.transform);
```

You want to access your script that is attached to the Sphere?

```
MyScript myscript = sphere.GetComponent<MyScript>();
```

You can't get stuff working in Unity by fiddling around. You will be wasting your time by doing this. Please follow a tutorial or one project from [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials). It should get you started.

Comment: Additionally you can tag game objects and use GameObject.FindWithTag or GameObject.GindGameObjectsWithTag.

Comment: Yes, you can. By reading the question, it looks OP doesn't know what tags are. OP just want to find GameObjects by name such as Hero and Sphere.